# Running user's input as command in Python Shell (interactive mode)

Tags: python, user-input, pythoninterpreter

I am wonder if it is possible to ask for a user input, run that as a command in the python interpreter and assigning the output to a variable. I would like to this like as if I was executing the command in Interactive Mode but inside a my own python script.

I have tried methods such as:

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

However, when using this method I have found several limitations this includes not being able to exit Interactive Mode and no ability to assign the output to variable.

For reference, this will be used for creating a python calculator.

Comment: [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#eval)?

Comment: Thankyou! You have just solve my problem!